# setting an IOS static lib architecture to "arm64" using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm building a static library for IOS as an xCode target (Cocoa touch static library). I try to "force" the archive product (.a file) or even the intermediate objects (.o files) to be built in "arm64" architecture. I do it using xCode Build Settings: 
[image]

After cleaning and building this target, I check the architecture using the terminal command `lipo -info`, but it looks like the architecture is x86_64: 
[image]

Something I missed in the way? how can I force my desired architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building you library for iOS simulator platform. Pick "Generic iOS Device" as target platform and you will get arm64 architecture.

You can set this setting in UI:
[image]

Or by passing `-sdk iphoneos` option to xcodebuild:

```
xcodebuild -project 44635297.xcodeproj -target 44635297 -configuration Release clean build -sdk iphoneos
```

Comment: Where can I change this setting? (In Supported Platforms I can see that iphonesimulator and iphoneos are set)

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Change 'Base SDK' in Build Settings to 'Latest iOS'.

[image]